# physical meaning of eigenvalue/vector

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a distance matrix M and have used [multidimensional scaling](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cmdscale.html) and it gives me some eigenvalues. How should I interpret such eigenvalues? Do they show some sort of variability or what? More practically, I really cannot understand the real meaning of eigenvalue. For example I can understand |M|, but I have no sense about the eigenvalue.

Comment: What's a distance matrix?

Comment: It is an Ecuadorian distance matrix between some objects

Comment: ref ?   (not in wikipedia)

Comment: Do you wonder about eigenvalues in general, or just for this matrix ? And why eigenvectors are not as issue as well, then ?

Comment: I still don't know what that means so I can't give you an answer specific to your matrix.  But the general idea of an eigenvector is that when you consider some endomorphism (a mapping from a vector space to itself), sometimes certain vectors (you can think of them as directions if you want) are not rotated, reflected, or moved in any other way by the endomorphism.  Those vectors are just *scaled*.  These vectors are called eigenvectors and eigenvalues are the scale *factors*.

Comment: Actually both! I also put a link on MDS in my question

Comment: @Bye_World: your answer is very good. I edited the question. So, why they are important? I mean how can we use such ability (not rotating, ...)

Comment: It can tell us interesting things about the endomorphism. For instance if you know that a matrix represents a reflection through a hyperplane, then the span of the eigenvectors will tell you which hyperplane you're reflecting through. Or if you have a matrix which scales some set of axes of your space, then the eigenvectors will be along those axes and the eigenvalues will be how much the axes are scaled by. Or if you have a matrix which projects vectors along a 1-d subspace, then the eigenvector with eigenvalue 1 will be parallel to the subspace and those with eigenvalue 0 will be orthogonal.

Comment: It was so mathematician :), I am an engineer and cannot understand those terminologies ! Does it show, for example in the provide link which is a distance matrix, variability or something?

Comment: if a matrix is an iterated transform, the largest eigenvalues will make their corresponding eigenvector more and more dominent ( mechanical vibrations, probabilistic graphs ) then become attractor.

Comment: You can get directly the matrix power n by transforming it to its canonical referential (if diagonalisable) then powering the eigenvalues.